# Core Data: How do I delete all objects with an attribute in Swift?

Tags: ios, core-data, swift

Say for simplicity that I have an entity named DOWJONES.  There are two attributes for every object ex AAPL and AAPL_NSDate.  ValueForKey:AAPL returns the stock price history and ValueforKey AAPL_NSDate the corresponding date.

How can I delete the stockprice history and corresponding date **quickly and efficiently** in swift?
This is how I query:

```
var appDel:AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate
    let context = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate).managedObjectContext!

    var request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "DOWJONES")
    request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
    var dowjones = context.executeFetchRequest(request, error: nil)! as [DOWJONES]
    var aapl = (dowjones as NSArray).valueForKey("AAPL") as NSArray
```

As suggested from @chris-wagner this is how I could iterate over the results and delete.

```
func deleteCoreDataObjects(){
    var request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "DOWJONES")
    request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
    var dowjones = context.executeFetchRequest(request, error: nil)!

    if dowjones.count > 0 {

        for result: AnyObject in dowjones{
            context.deleteObject(result as NSManagedObject)
            println("NSManagedObject has been Deleted")
        }
        context.save(nil)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do batch requests directly onto the data store as of iOS 8, using `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator`'s `executeRequest(_ request: NSPersistentStoreRequest, withContext context: NSManagedObjectContext, error error: NSErrorPointer)` method.

You create the persistent store request similarly to a fetch request, then pass it to the PSC using the above method.

Note however that you shouldn't have any in-context references to objects you're deleting with this method.

There's a nice explanation of it [here](http://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/new-in-core-data-and-ios-8-batch-updating/).

Comment: TIL! So much to keep up on :)

Answer (score 2):

Iterate over the results from your fetch request and call `self.context.deleteObject(_:)` on each one.

Comment: Is there really no faster way, like delete all of them at once?

Comment: Nope, not that I've seen. You could write a convenience method if you're going to be doing this often ;)